# A question about async() exception capture

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, exception

I am learning c++ concurrent programming. The code below confused me:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void func1() {
  list<int> l;
  while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
      l.push_back(i);
    }
    std::cout.put('.').flush();
  }
}

int main() {
  auto f1 = std::async(func1);
  try {
    f1.get();
  } catch (const exception &e) {
    cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
}
```

The output of the code:

```
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................[1]    23219 killed     ./demo
```

What I expected is the main thread can catch the exception raised from async thread. But in fact the async thread is just killed without catch. How to explain it?

My platform info:
`Darwin lsf-mbp.local 22.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0: Sun Oct  9 20:15:09 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8792.41.9~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64`

Any information are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you run this code from the main thread? What happens if you throw some dummy exception explicitly?

Comment: Are you sure that an exception is thrown in the first place? Some operating systems like to pretend that allocations are almost always possible and will succeed, so that no `std::bad_alloc` will be thrown, and will then kill a program (or even other memory-heavy programs) if it tries to access it without enough physical memory being available to map the allocated virtual memory to.

Comment: In fact I am not sure that an exception is thrown. I expected there should be a std::bad_alloc exception and caught by main thread. I think your explanation is reasonable.   @user17732522